# onsubmit of form, warn user and open in popup window?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, popup, submit

I have a form that when submitted I want the resulting window to be in a popup but before that I need a warning. If I do the following:

```
target="DoSubmit" onsubmit=" DoSubmit = window.open('about:blank','DoSubmit','width=500,height=350'); return confirm('Our Twitter account is set to private. If you click OK this will log a call with the Helpdesk and then take you to a page where you can request to follow us. Once we have approved the request you will be able to see our Tweets.');"
```

this will open the pop-up then show a warning putting the pop-up behind the window and carrying out the result of the form before the user has pressed OK or cancel. If I switch them around and put the warning before the popup, it just opens in a new tab rather than a popup with a fixed size. Can you help with this? The full form code is as follows:

```
<form name="TwitterSubscribe" id="TwitterSubscribe" action="./logconfirm_Twitter.php" method="post" target="DoSubmit" onsubmit=" DoSubmit = window.open('about:blank','DoSubmit','width=500,height=350'); return confirm('Our Twitter account is set to private. If you click OK this will log a call with the Helpdesk and then take you to a page where you can request to follow us. Once we have approved the request you will be able to see our Tweets.');">
          <input type="image" src="./images/twitter.png" onmouseover="this.src='./images/twitterHover.png';" onmouseout="this.src='./images/twitter.png';" />
          </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
<body>
...
<form id="myForm" action="x">
    <input type="submit" onclick="validateSubmit();return false;" />
</form>
<script>
function validateSubmit() {
    result = confirm("Our Twitter account is set to .....");
    if (result) {
        $('#myForm').submit();
    }
}
</script>
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do

```
if(confirm("...")) { 
    window.open(...); 
} else { 
    return false; 
}
```